# Clarifications on how to make interact jquery, ajax and php in order to realize a form submission and other controls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-submit

So, as the titles says, I need some clarifications on how to make interact jquery, ajax and php in order to realize a form submission and other controls.

This is my first web experience with jquery, ajax and php used all together, and, of course, I'm facing some problems.

I describe what I'm trying to do.

Basically, I've an index page with a registration form:

```
<form id="formRegistration" action="registration_success.php" method="post">
    <p id="ptxtFullName">
        <input id="txtFullName" name="txtFullName" class="textbox" placeholder="Insert you full name" type="text" />
    </p>

    <p id="pTxtEmail">
       <input id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" class="textbox" placeholder="Insert an email" type="text" />
    </p>

    <p id="pTxtPassword">
    <input id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" class="textbox" placeholder="Choose a password" type="password" />
    </p>

    <p id="pTxtPasswordConfirmation">
    <input id="txtPasswordConfirmation" name="txtPasswordConfirmation" class="textbox" placeholder="Confirm your password" type="password" />
    </p>

    <p id="pBtnRegistration">
    <input id="btnRegistration" type="submit" value="Register!" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Then, I've a jquery file, which does all the input validation things (some effects if the inputs are correct or incorrect, and things like these), and, if the validation went good, makes an ajax call.
This is only an example, I don't post the entire file, because it's quite huge:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(function() {

            var $fullName = $("input[name='txtFullName']");
            var $email = $("input[name='txtEmail']");
            var $password = $("input[name='txtPassword']");
            var $passwordConfirmation = $("input[name='txtPasswordConfirmation']");

    $("#btnRegistration").click(function() {
        //Validation controls and effects.
    });

    return true;

    });

    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "process_registration.php",
            data : "fullName", "email", "password",
            dataType : "HTML",
            success : function() {
                alert("Ok");
            },
            error : function() {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

});
```

NOTE that, the jquery file, when I add the ajax call, it stops to work, whilst if I don't add the ajax call, it works perfectly.

And then, here's my php file, named process_registration.php, wich is supposed to control if the email is already in use, and, after that, to insert the validated input datas into a MySQL database:

```
<?php
```

require 'db_connection.php';

```
$fullName = isset($_POST["fullName"]);
$email = isset($_POST["email"]);
$password = isset($_POST['password']);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utente WHERE mail = '$email'") or die("Email already in use");

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if ($num_rows == 0) 
{
    $password_md5 = md5($password);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (Full_Name , Email, Password) VALUES
               ('$fullName', '$email', '$password_md5')") OR DIE(mysql_error());
}
```

Thats all.

Obviously it isn't working.

Maybe I'm adopting a completely wrong approach in this thing?

Thanks in advance for your kindess and your answers.

Comment: Try to use PDO instead of mysql_query function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#formRegistration').submit(function() {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Perform form validation here and return from this function
        // if you do not want to submit the form.

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "process_registration.php",
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            dataType : 'html',
            success : function() {
                alert("Ok");
            },
            error : function() {
               alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This registers an event handler that gets called when the form is going to be submitted. The call to `e.preventDefault()` prevents the regular form submission. Then the handler posts the form via ajax.

You'll have to change the names of the input elements though because they need to match the names your PHP code is looking for (e.g., change "txtFullName" to "fullName").

Comment: Ok, finally it works! Big thanks! You literally saved me, thanks again.

Comment: @DTLTE - You're welcome. It it helped, you should select the answer by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

The data attribute in the ajax call is supposed to be an object.

```
data : {
    "fullName" : fullName,
    "email" : email
}
```